# How to setup a Wi-Fi 2-computer network with Internet sharing?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, setup

I have the following devices:

1. Desktop Computer (Windows XP Professional)
2. Laptop Computer (Windows Vista Home Premium)
3. A USB modem that I want to connect to my Desktop computer (so my Desktop has Internet)
4. And a Wi-Fi router (D-Link, model: DIR-300) that I want to use in order to create a connection between mentioned two computers to be able to share files and what is the most ***important thing to make my laptop*** to have access to the Internet.

What steps I should do to have this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying you are going to dial in with the desktop to the internet then want to share your desktop's connection with the laptop?

Get your desktop working with the Internet.

Connect your desktop and laptop through the wifi router as a switch so they can see each other, at which point you know they're on the same subnetwork. Ping is the utility included on Windows that you want to make friends with for this.

Set up internet connection sharing on XP. See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126).

That should be the overview of what would be needed...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this information is not enough for me. Please tell me in detail what operations I should do on each computer. What type of connections I should create? Seems I have two problems:

1. Some IP conflict
2. And that I should plug-in a "Lan cable" Ethernet cable to the Wi-Fi router to got the router to work properly

Have read the article as well, but no progress ...

Comment: You may need to break it down into individual steps, as what you're asking for it like asking how to build a car. Do you have your PC connected to the Internet through the modem?

Comment: Yes, I do! I have the Desktop connected to the Internet, but I can't get connected the Laptop to the Desktop properly. I don't know how to configure the Desktop and Laptop, to have internet on Laptop.

Comment: Now, do you have the laptop able to see the desktop? Use ipconfig on the two computers to make sure you have networking set up. You might need DHCP on the wifi router to hand out addresses to the laptop (and/or desktop). You might need to check that the Windows firewall is off so you can ping the two machines to check connectivity between the two.

Comment: No I can't see the desktop from my laptop. Can't understand the problem :(

Comment: Then step back and first use ipconfig on the laptop and on the desktop to see if they are on the same subnet. Read your docs for the switch and see if it's configured to hand out DHCP addresses, and that both of your machines are getting addresses on that subnet.

Comment: The problem is that when Laptop see the files that shared on Desktop it doesn't see Internet and vice versa.

Comment: The first thing to verify is your network is set up properly. Can the laptop ping the desktop, and can the desktop ping the laptop? Then set up Internet Connection Sharing as per the MS article, and that should handle the forwarding of the network requests from the laptop. But you need to make sure your network is set up properly.